# Google Chart API : Can page number be shown in Table while paging is enabled?

Tags: google-visualization

I use Google Chart API.

Can page number be shown in Table while paging is enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page number will automatically show up just by using `"page: 'enable'"` while giving table options.

```
   var tab_options = {title: 'Table View',
        showRowNumber: true,
        width: '100%',
        hieght: '50%',
        page: 'enable',
        pageSize: '10',
        // pagingSymbols: {prev: ['< prev'],next: ['next >']},
        allowHtml: true,
        alternatingRowStyle: true}

    // Instantiate and Draw our Table
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(div_id));

    table.clearChart();
    table.draw(TableData, tab_options);
```

Refer more [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table)